# Trying to deploy ionic5 angular8 pwa to aws ec2 from azure devops YAML

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am new to azure devops.I am trying to deploy my ionic5 angular application on amazon ec2 via azure pipelines.Whenever i am trying to run the pipeline it is giving "Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
/build-ci.yml (Line: 2, Col: 3): A mapping was not expected" this error.
This is yaml file code.I am quite stucked here. Please help.

```
trigger:
- task: CodeDeployDeployApplication@1
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'AWS Service Con'
    regionName: 'us-east-1'
    applicationName: 'Dev-erp-Frontend'
    deploymentGroupName: 'Dev-erp-Frontend'
    deploymentRevisionSource: 'workspace'
    revisionBundle: 'Dev-erp-Frontend-Rev'
    bucketName: 'Dev-erp-Frontend'
    fileExistsBehavior: 'OVERWRITE'
    batch: "true"
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - dev
  paths:
    include:
      - ./*

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - dev
  paths:
    include:
      - ./*

jobs:
  - job: Build_Job
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-18.04'
      demands:
      - npm
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      clean: false
#    - powershell: 'npm cache clean  --force'
#      displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
#      env:
#        APPDATA: npm-cache
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'Npm Install'
      inputs:
        workingDir: "./"
        command: "ci"
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'Lint Client App'
      inputs:
        workingDir: "./"
        command: "custom"
        customCommand: "run lint"
      continueOnError: true
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'Copy Assets'
      inputs:
        workingDir: "./"
        command: "custom"
        customCommand: "run copy-files"
      continueOnError: false
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'Build Client App'
      inputs:
        workingDir: "./"
        command: "custom"
        customCommand: "run build:prod"

# Archive files
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)' 
        includeRootFolder: true 
        archiveType: 'zip' # Options: zip, 7z, tar, wim
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/www.zip' 
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        Contents: 'www/**'
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'titas-ecom-erp'
```

Comment: Hi @Amitabh Biswas, Any update here? Please feel free to let me know the latest news. Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: No concern till now. The yaml file is working smoothly. No issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot set the task CodeDeployDeployApplication@1 at the [trigger level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#triggers), we should add the [task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#task) at the [steps level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#steps). You can update your YAML definition as follows.

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - dev
  paths:
    include:
      - ./*

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - dev
  paths:
    include:
      - ./*

jobs:
  - job: Build_Job
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-18.04'
      demands:
      - npm
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      clean: false
#    - powershell: 'npm cache clean  --force'
#      displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
#      env:
#        APPDATA: npm-cache

    - task: CodeDeployDeployApplication@1
      inputs:
        awsCredentials: 'AWS Service Con'
        regionName: 'us-east-1'
        applicationName: 'Dev-erp-Frontend'
        deploymentGroupName: 'Dev-erp-Frontend'
        deploymentRevisionSource: 'workspace'
        revisionBundle: 'Dev-erp-Frontend-Rev'
        bucketName: 'Dev-erp-Frontend'
        fileExistsBehavior: 'OVERWRITE'
        batch: "true"

    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'Npm Install'
      inputs:
        workingDir: "./"
        command: "ci"
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'Lint Client App'
      inputs:
        workingDir: "./"
        command: "custom"
        customCommand: "run lint"
      continueOnError: true
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'Copy Assets'
      inputs:
        workingDir: "./"
        command: "custom"
        customCommand: "run copy-files"
      continueOnError: false
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'Build Client App'
      inputs:
        workingDir: "./"
        command: "custom"
        customCommand: "run build:prod"

# Archive files
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)' 
        includeRootFolder: true 
        archiveType: 'zip' # Options: zip, 7z, tar, wim
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/www.zip' 
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        Contents: 'www/**'
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'titas-ecom-erp'
```